# How to retrieve a class object inside the dictionary in python?

Tags: python

I have added a employee class object inside a dictionary successfully .But i am not able to get back the value from the same dictionary? Below are the code and output.

**source code:**

```
# decalre a dict
employee_collection = {}

# Class object to store employee's details
class employee:
  # Constructor
  def __init__(self,name,age):
    self.name = name
    self.age  = age

  # Display the object values
  def print_property(self):
    print(f"name is {self.name} and age is {str(self.age)}")

# loop to add multiple employee details
for x in range(1, 6):
  obj= employee("xxx", 28+x)
  employee_collection.update({x : obj})

 # extract the employee detail from  and print the vaue to user
for x in employee_collection:
  # print(x.name)
  print(x)

print(employee_collection)
```

**output :**

```
1
2
3
4
5
{1: <__main__.employee object at 0x0327F610>, 2: <__main__.employee object at 0x03550C70>, 3: <__main__.employee object at 0x03550580>, 4: <__main__.employee object at 0x035503B8>, 5: <__main__.employee object at 0x03550FB8>}
```

**My question is:**
How to print the name and age using loop in main method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two methods. The dict is storing the **instance** of each `employee` (which should be `Employee` btw).

You can either print the properties of the instance, or change what happens when you try to print an object.

**The former:**

```
for key, e in employee_collection.items():
    print(f'{x} {e.name} {e.age}')
```

**The latter:**

```
class Employee:
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} {self.age}'


for e in employee_collection.values():
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 2):

To iterate through a dictionary you can use its `keys()`, `values()` or `items()`. Since you want both the key (x) and the value (employee) you want to use `items()` which returns all dictionary key-value pairs as so-called `tuple` in a list:

```
for x, employee in employee_collection.items():
    print(f'Number: {x}, Name: {employee.name}, age: {employee.age}')  # this is printing a format-string
```

Comment: That's not what's in `employee_collection`.